# Drupal.ajax() vs JQuery/$.ajax() – what is difference?

Tags: 8, ajax

[Official manual](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/ajax-api/ajax-dialog-boxes) says

> This scenario doesn't seems allow behaviours (to be confirmed)

Does it mean that Drupal.ajax()

shouldn't be called inside Drupal.behaviors.my_func

and/or inside JQuery's $.ajax?

Drupal.dialog() in

```
Drupal.behaviors... 
  $.ajax..
    success: function (response) { 
      here 
    }
```

works smoothly for D9.4.1 core.

Comment: Drupal.ajax() is a wrapper for $.ajax with a predefined success function executing the Ajax commands Drupal returns.

Comment: As side note, that documentation is written by the community; it's not the official documentation. What you quoted is a comment from a user who edited the documentation and put his comment. It's just a comment that should have not put into the documentation. The *Discuss* page is for discussing what should be changed in the documentation page and what should be added; the user should have used it to ask more information, if he wasn't sure about the added example works in every case.